# With "A" or not

Tags: grammar

For the following sentences..
"We believe that strong bonding between parents and school can...."
"We believe that a strong bonding between parents and school can...."

Which one is correct?
Do we need "A" in this sentence?

Comment: "I'd prefer "A strong bond between..." but that doesn't strictly answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "bonding" is a gerund, which can act as a noun. Therefore, using "a" before "strong bonding" is correct, though it is not absolutely necessary. In my opinion, it is somewhat of a style question. I personally prefer this sentence with an article, which puts an emphasis on "strong bonding".
Here are some [further](https://www.quora.com/Which-article-should-be-used-before-a-verb-when-we-are-treating-it-as-a-noun) [forum](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=21154) [threads](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118335/cases-of-using-an-article-before-the-gerund/162443)!